# Does gevent.monkey.patch_all() patch file objects?

Tags: python, asynchronous, gevent

I noticed that gevent supports wrappers for file-like objects:
http://www.gevent.org/gevent.fileobject.html

`gevent.monkey.patch_all` conveniently patches modules like `socket` and `time` to make them `gevent` friendly. Reading the [code](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/blob/master/gevent/monkey.py), it doesn't seem like `patch_all()` calls an explicit `patch_file()` but it does call `patch_builtins()`. The implementation of this function is somewhat magical. It's not clear to me whether this would patch the built-in `file` objects.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the built in `file` is not patched. You need to use `gevent` `FileObject`.